# Query to calculate average resolve time based on quarter

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table having attributes: ticket#, closed date & resolve time.
I need to write a SQL query to calculate the average resolve time in each quarter.

eg in quarter1: 5 tickets are closed (10 days,1 day,3, day,1day.10 days) are resolved time for each ticket 
then average resolve time is 5 days
output should be  as below

```
Quarter  days    
Q1       5    
Q2       2 (similarly)   
Q3       7   
Q4       9
```

sample data

[image]

I really stuck in this query

Comment: Can you explain with a minimal and reproducible sample query where you were stuck.

Comment: look at this:
[T-SQL calculating average time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349586/t-sql-calculating-average-time)

Comment: "SQL Developer" is a SQL tool only for the oracle database, it can't be used with SQL Server. I re-tagged the question with `oracle` instead of `sql-server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** This code is tested on Oracle Database. For any syntax related error, you can replace according to you database.
Also, ***update your column name,date,timestamp,timezone and table name accordingly***.

The sample query is like this ...

```
 select temp.quarter,avg(resolve_time) 

from 
    (
    select resolve_time,
    CASE  
    WHEN (close_date between TO_DATE('2019-APR-01 00:00','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') and TO_DATE('2019-JUN-30 23:59','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')) THEN 1
    WHEN (close_date between TO_DATE('2019-JUL-01 00:00','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') and TO_DATE('2019-SEP-30 23:59','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')) THEN 2
    WHEN (close_date between TO_DATE('2019-OCT-01 00:00','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') and TO_DATE('2019-DEC-31 23:59','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')) THEN 3
    WHEN (close_date between TO_DATE('2020-JAN-01 00:00','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') and TO_DATE('2020-MAR-31 23:59','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')) THEN 4
    ELSE 0 END quarter
    from TestStack
    ) temp 

group by temp.quarter;
```

Comment: Far to much code to write, simply do `GROUP BY TRUNC(close_date, 'Q')`

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this.

```
SELECT AVG(resolvetime) AS 'Average Resolve Time' 
FROM [TableName]
WHERE closeddate BETWEEN [Start date of Quarter] AND [End date of Quarter]
```

Comment: itried as per suggestion as per LahiruK717          SELECT  avg(p.resolvetime) as AverageRT
FROM sampletable
WHERE closeddate BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-09-30'                            but unable to get desired result